# How do you disconnect a Xbox 360 controller from a PC

Tags: pc, xbox-360, controllers

I'm trying to disconnect my Xbox 360 controller from my PC and connect it to my Xbox but I can't figure out how to disconnect it. How would I do this?

Comment: Is your controller connected via wireless/bluetooth?

Comment: I'd imagine you could just hold the sync button on your controller and console and connect them.

Comment: The only way that I have found is to pop the battery compartment (which is quick). But I imagine you want a key or button shortcut right?

Comment: Remember, that if you have paired bluetooth device like headphones or wireless controller, then it is very possible that your computer tries to connect with it automatically. In Bluetooth settings (in the case of Windows 10) you can "unpair" the device and then probably it will stop trying to establish a connection with your PC.

Answer (score -4):

If it's wired, you should only have to unplug it.

Comment: Chances are it's connected wirelessly